# Automapper mapping issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I need to map a model to a viewmodel using AutoMapper.

Model:

```
[Table("News")]
public class News
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePostedOn { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
}

[Table("Pictures")]
public class Picture
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<News> News { get; set; }
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
public class HomeViewModels
{
    public IList<HomeMainNews> MainNews { get; private set; }
}

public class HomeMainNews
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string PictureURL { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<News, HomeMainNews>();
```

How can I map a News that have a set of Pictures, to a viewmodel with only one picture according to a certain condition "Type = 2"

Current solution:

```
    vm.MainNews = db.News
              .Select(n => new HomeMainNews { 
                                Id = n.Id,
                                Date = n.DatePostedOn.ToString(),
                                Title = n.Title,
                                PictureURL = n.Pictures.Where(p => p.Type == 1).Select(p => p.Filename).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
                        }).ToList();
```

Automapper solution:

```
    vm.MainNews = db.News.Project().To<HomeMainNews>().ToList();
```

Comment: For something so simple (4 fields in your VM) I would not use Automapper for this especially if one of the fields has some custom work. you can simply use `HomeViewModels view = new HomeViewModels ( MainNews = news.Select(Map) )` where Map is a method that lives in your controller returning a `HomeMainNews` that maps those 3 basis fields and the logic around the 4th field.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Can you share an example?

Comment: what have you tried? i cant provide an example without just doing it for you. I have given you the basic structure in my first comment

Comment: Hi @wal I have updated the question with the current solution

Comment: Looks good @Patrick except you should remove the `ToString` at the end of this line `PictureURL = n.Pictures.Where(p => p.Type == 1).Select(p => p.Filename).FirstOrDefault().ToString()` as its not required and will throw a `NullPointerException` if there are no pictures with `Type == 1`

Comment: I have tested @conanak99 solution (check the question edit) and it's working fine, but now my concern is regarding performace, what is your opinion?

Comment: The collection of Picture is already loaded to News object when you get the News object from database. The mapping happened in server side, not database side, so you don't have to worry about the performance.
Be careful that it will throw NullPointerException if the News object doesn't have any picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<News, HomeMainNews>()
            .ForMember(mainNew => mainNew.Date, opt => opt.MapFrom(news => news.DatePostedOn))
            .ForMember(mainNew => mainNew.PictureURL, opt => opt.MapFrom(news => news.Pictures.First(pic => pic.Type == 2).Filename));
```

Comment: It's working fine! Great! What about performance regarding my Linq query?

Comment: Check the SQL to find out. It wouldn't be much different with LINQ.

Comment: Hi @JimmyBogard thanks, I will check. BTW great job regarding AutoMapper, I use it in all my projects since day 1 ;)